# Replacing Text with Javascript on Shopify Cart Page

Tags: javascript, shopify

In this store - https://commonfibers.com/cart - there's a private app that is creating line item properties on some products.  Example - https://gyazo.com/aa86c0696b406e5c128df7640f353c7f.

I want to clean up the display of the line item properties.  So this text:
     Art: 'Art - Blank (e9bd8c48c4134298bb9013bb595d8c6b)'
would instead look like this:
     Art: 'Art - Blank'

I have created this .liquid file:

```
<script>

  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var divArt = document.getElementsByClassName('property-Art');
    var text = divArt.innerText;
    for (var i = 0; i < divArt.length; i++) {
      var text = divArt[i].innerText;
      console.log("Beginning text - " + text);
      text = text.replace(/\s*\(.*?\)\s*/g, '');
      console.log("Processed text - " + text);
      console.log("innerText - " + divArt[i].innerText);
    };
  }, false);

</script>
```

And its working in that it removes the unwanted content.  **What I'm stuck on is how to insert the processed text back into the DOM so it shows up in the browser.**  I can see the replace logic works as I'm console.log it - https://gyazo.com/6f3aed206ccd08343dc50415c8dcae01.  But my efforts to get it to display to the user have failed so far.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign the result `text` back to something. Try adding this at the end of your function:

`divArt[i].innerText = text;`

Comment: Bingo!  Thanks a ton.  Here's the updated JS:

<script>
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var divArt = document.getElementsByClassName('property-Art');
    var text = divArt.innerText;
    for (var i = 0; i < divArt.length; i++) {
      var text = divArt[i].innerText;
      text = text.replace(/\s*\(.*?\)\s*/g, '');
      divArt[i].innerText = text;
    };
  }, false);
</script>